# How to determine if a branch has no parent commits

Tags: git

I am writing some tooling that needs to know whether the current branch location/commit has no parents. (This could come about most likely by being a fresh repository with no commits, or a deliberately orphaned branch.) I need a way to check command line output/exit codes so this can be done within a program and automated.

Ideally, this could be accomplished only using git plumbing commands, but failing an easy way to do that, I can work with git porcelain commands.

How can I reliably and succinctly determine if a git branch is an orphan or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that orphan branches don't really exist.

Really, this is literally the case.  In a new repository with no commits, there are no branches:

```
$ mkdir tt
$ cd tt
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ git branch
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

(the `No commits yet` output is relatively new, in Git version 2.14).

A branch that has no commits on it literally does not exist.  This is why the name `master` does not show up in the `git branch` output: branch master doesn't exist, even though we're on it.

What's happened is that Git has stored the desired branch name into `HEAD`:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

but the branch itself does not exist:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The same thing happens immediately after any `git checkout --orphan` command: the symbolic reference `HEAD` does exist, but it points to no commit, so that `git rev-parse HEAD` fails.

In a script, use `git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD` to check for this state.  Since `HEAD` *always* exists as a name,<sup>1</sup> it will fail to parse if and only if it contains the name of a branch that does not exist.  **Edit**: Or, as [jthill notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140287/how-to-determine-if-a-branch-has-no-parent-commits/47141310?noredirect=1#comment81235649_47141310), use `git cat-file -e HEAD`.  The rev-parse command will print the hash ID of the current commit if `HEAD` is valid, so that one must be redirected somewhere.  Both commands exit 0 if `HEAD` is valid, nonzero if not.

Now, there's another, *different* case, which [Ôrel has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140460/1256452), which occurs when two branches do exist, but are not in any way related:

```
A--B--C   <-- master

D--E--F   <-- independent
```

This is an example of a repository with six total commits (labeled `A` through `F` here instead of using real hash IDs), and two branch names.  Neither branch is related to the other, so `master` and `indepedent` have no commits in common, no matter how far back you traverse the history from either branch-tip.

The easiest way to test if two branches are unrelated is to use `git merge-base`.  The merge base(s) of two branch tips is/are the commits that are "closest to" the tips but that are in the ancestry chain of each tip.  In graph terms, they are the Lowest Common Ancestor nodes.  Typically there is exactly one such node, though in the case of criss-cross merges there may be two, and in the case of unrelated branches, there are none.

If `git merge-base` says there are none, the two branches are unrelated.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you remove the `HEAD` file, Git refuses to believe that the repository *is* a repository.  This can happen if you get a kernel panic / system crash, since the file `HEAD` tends to be pretty active and might get removed by the post-crash file system cleanup.  If it does happen, writing `ref: refs/heads/master` into `.git/HEAD` can save everything for you. :-)

Comment: The case where the branches are unrelated is not relevant to my use-case but is nonetheless interesting. The information around `rev-parse --verify` was most helpful and solves this issue for me. +1

Comment: I think `git cat-file -e HEAD` might be a better core-command existence test.

Comment: @jthill: interesting; that does eliminate the need to capture or redirect the `git rev-parse --verify -q HEAD` output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `--is-ancestor`

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <maybe-ancestor-commit> <descendant-commit>
```

From the doc

> --is-ancestor
>
> Check if the first is an ancestor of the second , and exit with status
>   0 if true, or with status 1 if not. Errors are signaled by a non-zero
>   status that is not 1.

You can test from the initial commit

To get the initial commit

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

Your script can be

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`  TheBranchToTest
```

Comment: So how does this tell me that there is no ancestor whatsoever for a given commit?

Comment: I have updated my response, I presume you want to test against the initial commit `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`

Comment: This fails with `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` when there are no prior commits. In the case of a fresh repository, there aren't any initial commits, right?

Answer (score 0):

As git chains commits with *hashes*, if there is no # associated with branch name - then it signifies it's orphaned branch & is not linked to others

Get name of current branch you are on :

```
git branch | grep "^*" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Run git branch in **verbose** mode & simply look for if there is hash!

```
git branch -v | grep `git branch | grep "^*" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

We can write more parsing on top of this as per need