# Moving the content of one branch in a repo to another branch under the another repo

Tags: github

I have one branch name branch1 under the main Repository Repo1.

I want to move the content of branch1 to another branch which exists under another repo say repo2. So it's like:

- `Repo1-> branch 1` (latest code).
- `Repo2-> branch 2` ( empty branch).

I want to move content or copy the content from `branch 1 -> branch 2`.
Can you please help me go through a few solutions?

Comment: I found the solutions. please review it        1. go to project location and launch git bash 2. git checkout branch name1 (the branch is already created and pushed in git hub ) 3. git remote add new ( destination repo URL )  eg: https://github.com/username/repo name.git 4 . git push new branch name 1 .     verify whether branch name 1 is present under the destination repo

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed push any branch to another repository.
Howver, then end reuslt will be an orphan branch in the second repository

```bash
cd /path/to/repo1
git switch branch1
git remote add repo2 /url/repo2
git push repo2 branch1
```

The new branch would not be [related with any other repo2 branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47141310/6309) though:

```bash
cd /path/to
git clone /url/repo2
git merge-base main origin/branch1 
<nothing>
```